# How to remove character between starting from stars *** including stars also from column inlincidentdetails_mem in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: Description details]

Result I am getting:

```
*** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We are sending him to jail case closed    *** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We have found 1 person guilty
```

I want to remove everything between the star including start too

This is the result I need:

```
We are sending him to jail case closed We have found 1 person guilty
```

Comment: I've removed all the tags here apart from [[tag:sql]] here as several conflict. Please [edit] your question and tag only the RDBMS and tags that are relevant to *your* environment.

Comment: Did you read the tag excerpt for [[tag:rdbms]]? It doesn't tell us what RDBMS you are *really* using. Though the above screenshot *looks* like a screenshot of SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) which is the IDE for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you are using SQL Server (based on the screenshot of SSMS), then this isn't particularly easy. SQL Server doesn't support Regex, so you can't do anything like Regex replacement without a CLR function.

What you could do instead is split the string, using `'***'` as the delimiter, and only return values with odd number positions, and then rebuild the string. Unfortunately SQL server's built in delimited string splitter, `STRING_SPLIT`, doesn't provide the ordinal position of each item, so you'll need to use a user defined one. I'll be using [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) here.

I'm also going to *assume* you are on a recent version of SQL Server, and thus can use `STRING_AGG` and `TRIM`. If not, you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) method to aggregate your string and `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` instead of `TRIM`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourString varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('*** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We are sending him to jail case closed    *** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We have found 1 person guilty');
GO

SELECT STRING_AGG(TRIM(DS.Item),' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(REPLACE(YT.YourString,'***','|'),'|') DS --Replace *** with a character that doesn't appear in your string
WHERE DS.ItemNumber % 2 = 1
  AND DS.Item <> ''
GROUP BY YT.YourString;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae8c46f13a36f20856400b929b9b20a1)

Answer (score 1):

Another method by using XQuery. XQuery data model is based on *ordered sequences*. Exactly what we need for the task to retrieve odd vs. even tokens in the string. It is done via `mod` operator.

It is for SQL Server 2012 onwards.

No need for any third-party functions.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (tokens varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES('*** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We are sending him to jail case closed    *** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We have found 1 person guilty');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(3) = '***';

SELECT *
    , c.query('
    for $x in /root/r[position() mod 2 eq 1]
    return $x
    ').value('data(.)[1] cast as xs:token?', 'varchar(8000)') AS result
FROM @tbl
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);;
```

**Output**

```
We are sending him to jail case closed We have found 1 person guilty
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `String_Split()` which is a builtin function in SQL Server 2016 and up. And then used coalesce to concatenate the strings to bring the answer. You can edit the query according to the data that you have as well. For an example, you can bring a table with the column as I have hard coded the actual string.

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(MAX); 

SELECT 
    @val = COALESCE( @val + '' + A.[Value], A.[Value] )
FROM
    (SELECT [value]  
     FROM STRING_SPLIT('*** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We are sending him to jail case closed    *** 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ***  We have found 1 person guilty', '*')  -- This can be brought through a table as well. 
    ) AS A 
WHERE 
    LEN(A.[value]) > LEN(' 09-06-2021 12:10 (Admin) ')

SELECT @val
```

[image: Result]